# Phonegap Paypal Plugin - Recurring Payments?

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, paypal

I've just managed to setup the Paypal plugin for Phonegap (Iphone - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PayPalPlugin) which works fine for individual payment.

But does anyone know if this method can be used to trigger a recurring payment?

This is the current trigger code -

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
    try {

    // do your thing!
    document.addEventListener(PayPal.PaymentEvent.Success, onPaymentSuccess,false);
    document.addEventListener(PayPal.PaymentEvent.Canceled, onPaymentCanceled,false);
    document.addEventListener(PayPal.PaymentEvent.Failed, onPaymentFailed,false);

    window.plugins.paypal.prepare(PayPal.PaymentType.DONATION);
    window.plugins.paypal.setPaymentInfo({
            paymentCurrency : "USD",
            paymentAmount : "00.10",
            itemDesc : "network cable",
            recipient : "pabs_1355160222_biz@liquidsolution.co.uk",
            merchantName : "test Account"
    });

    } catch (e) {
        debug.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having read through the frustratingly limited documentation for this plugin and scanning the source code - I now don't think its possible to make recurring payments (please correct me if i'm wrong) - the plugin doesnt seem to trigger an overlay when in sandbox or live mode either - and doesn't display any errors - so i'm not even sure if its still functional!  This Paypal/Phonegap implementation is driving me nuts - if anyone has any advice for an alternative - please let me know!  Cheers

Comment: This plugin is now undergoing a complete overhaul and re-write under new management. Are you still having issues?

Comment: Cool - great news - I haven't actually tried since - moved on to a different part of the project with a view of revisiting next week!  I'll have another go if its being rewritten. Cheers

Comment: @Dancer Did you integrate recurring Paypal now? Actually I am also looking for this

Answer (score 0):

The initial plugin was faulty. It has been re-written and now lives at http://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin and has been successfully tested in Sandbox mode.

As far as the recurring payments this is not possible at this time with the current PayPal-SDK from PayPal. If they release an updated SDK that includes this feature it will be added to the plugin.